# caffe - How can I reduce size of input images for googlenet training

Tags: caffe

I am using googlenet model and I want to use a different image size for training (a smaller version of the image) , the image_mean and lmdb files have the reduced size as well . When I modified the size in the googlenet.prototxt and ran the train.sh file the program is being aborted with the following error.

- Check failure stack trace: ***
     @     0x7fdbb9499daa  (unknown)
     @     0x7fdbb9499ce4  (unknown)
     @     0x7fdbb94996e6  (unknown)
     @     0x7fdbb949c687  (unknown)
     @     0x7fdbb99543ee  caffe::Blob<>::Reshape()
     @     0x7fdbb9954619  caffe::Blob<>::Reshape()
     @     0x7fdbb98dcc08  caffe::PoolingLayer<>::Reshape()
     @     0x7fdbb99968ac  caffe::Net<>::Init()
     @     0x7fdbb9997725  caffe::Net<>::Net()
     @     0x7fdbb985174a  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
     @     0x7fdbb985284c  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
     @     0x7fdbb9852b7a  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
     @     0x7fdbb984a263  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
     @           0x40e67e  caffe::SolverRegistry<>::CreateSolver()
     @           0x40794b  train()
     @           0x40590c  main
     @     0x7fdbb87a7f45  (unknown)
     @           0x406041  (unknown)
     @              (nil)  (unknown) Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the size for googlenet model is fixed and unique , so modifying it will result in an error. So its mandatory to maintain the same size as required by the model to train.